# Nav positioned at the bottom, need the inner lists to appear above instead of below the nav?

Tags: html, css, nav

Below is my HTML code for a nav with sub lists. The sub lists drop downwards and I want them to open upwards as the nav is located at the bottom part of the page, how can I do this?

I have set up a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/b58Yj/1/

```
<ul id="nav">
<li>
    <a id="lfw-link" href="london-fashion-week.html">
        Live at London Fashion Week
    </a>
    <nav id="lfw-nav">
        <a href="london-fashion-week.html">
            SEE ALL
        </a>
        <a href="lee-roach.html">
  Lee Roach
        </a> <a href="xander-zhou.html">Xander Zhou</a>
        <a href="vivienne-westwood-2013.html">
            Vivienne Westwood 2013
        </a>
        <a href="paul-smith.html">
            Paul smith
        </a>
        <a href="house-of-holland.html">
            House of Holland
        </a>
        <a href="roksanda.html">
            Roksanda
        </a>
        <a href="julien-mcdonald.html">
            Julien Mcdonald
        </a>
        <a href="vivienne-westwood-2012.html">
            Vivienne Westwood 2012
        </a>
        <a href="2012-lfw.html">
            London Fashion Week 2012
        </a>
    </nav>

</li>
<li>
    <a id="clients-link" href="clients.html">
        Clients
    </a>
    <nav id="clients-nav">
        <a href="clients.html">
            SEE ALL
        </a>
        <a href="yoga-project.html">
        Yoga Project
        </a>
        <a href="edward-sharpe.html">
            Edward Sharpe and the magnetic zeros
        </a>
        <a href="tank-magazine.html">
            Tank Magazine
        </a>
        <a href="volt-magazine.html">
            Volt Magazine
        </a>
        <a href="poplin.html">
            Poplin
        </a>
        <a href="dash-magazine.html">
            Dash Magazine
        </a>
        <a href="tank-o-magazine.html">
            O Tank Magazine
        </a>
        <a href="grit-magazine.html">
            Grit Magazine
        </a>
        <a href="gieves-and-hawkes.html">
            Gieves and Hawkes
        </a>
    </nav>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="personal-link" href="personal.html">
        Personal Projects
    </a>
    <nav id="personal-nav">
        <a href="personal.html">
            SEE ALL
        </a>
        <a href="other-drawings.html">
            Other Drawings
        </a>
        <a href="head-in-the-clouds.html">
            Head in the Clouds
        </a>
        <a href="restless.html">
            Restless
        </a>
        <a href="acne-sample-lookbook.html">
            Acne Sample LookBook
        </a>
        <a href="men-interupted.html">
            Men Interupted
        </a>
    </nav>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="video-link" href="tank-magazine-stop-motion.html">
        Video
    </a>
    <nav id="video-nav">

        <a href="tank-magazine-stop-motion.html">
            Tao Lin Interview Tank Magazine
        </a>
    </nav>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="about.html">
        About
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="contact.html">
        Contact
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
    position:absolute;
    bottom:18px; 
    left:0;
```

to  `#nav>li:hover>nav`

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b58Yj/2/)**

So that the sub-menu opens from the bottom -> upwards

Comment: `bottom:100%;` would be better as it's pixel independent.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this jsfiddle over here, examine the code and you'll get what you need
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W5FWW/1/)

```
#nav:hover ul li:hover ul {
position: absolute;
margin-top: 1px;
font: 10px;
bottom: 100%;
```

}